# Why I can't borrow immutable reference of a mutable reference

Tags: rust

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let r = &mut v;
let rr = &r;
r.push(4);
println!("{:?}, {:?}", r, rr);
```

Gives error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*r` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
   |
86 |     let rr = &r;
   |              -- immutable borrow occurs here
87 |     r.push(4);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
88 |     println!("{:?}, {:?}", r, rr);
   |                               -- immutable borrow later used here
```

I understand the concept of immutable reference can not be borrowed for `*r`, if there is already a borrowed mutable reference of `*r`. However, in this case I am trying to borrow immutable reference of `r`, not of `*r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference is just a variable, like any other variable.

If you replace the variable `r` with an integer, you should see why this isn't possible:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut r = 10;
    let rr = &r;
    r += 2;
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", r, rr);
}
```

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `r` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
3 |     let rr = &r;
  |              -- borrow of `r` occurs here
4 |     r += 2;
  |     ^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `r` occurs here
5 |     println!("{:?}, {:?}", r, rr);
  |                               -- borrow later used here
```

Any mutable variable automatically becomes immutable while an immutable reference to it exists.

If that weren't the case, the owner of the `rr` variable couldn't rely on the fact that the content of `rr` never changes while he has the reference, which is one of the main points of immutable references. It doesn't just mean that you can't modify the variable, but you can also rely on the fact that no one else modifies it while you hold the reference.

So the pure existence of `rr` makes `r` temporarily immutable. `r` will automatically become mutable again once `rr` stops existing, but as you `println!(/*..*/, rr)` later, you force `rr` to stay alive until then and you force `r` to be immutable. That's why the modification fails.

The fact that in your code `r` is a reference doesn't change anything about this language mechanism. In your code, if this wouldn't error, the value `rr` references would change while `rr` exists. And again, the fact that `rr` is an immutable reference guarantees that the content that `rr` is referencing won't change.

---

*Remark:* The way I worded 'mutability' in this answer is somewhat incomplete, as 'interior mutability' exists, but it was easier to describe it this way. In reality, the words 'mutability' and 'immutability' should be replaced with 'exclusive access' and 'non-exclusive access'.

Comment: Thanks. It's a very good analogy. Given the error messages are different, do you mean "assign to" and "borrow .. as mutable" are the same from compiler's perspective on mutability?

Comment: @HelinWang Both are different actions, but both require mutable access. Assigning requires mutable access to a variable, and calling a `&mut self` method also requires mutable access to the variable it is called on. `Vec::push()` requires `&mut self` as a parameter, so that's where the "borrow as mutable" comes from. Rust automatically borrows a variable mutably if you call a `&mut self` method on it.